# The conceal feature in vim still makes me move over all the characters

Tags: vim

Here is what I do
`:syntax match conceal Test +[A-Z0-9]\{6}+`
`:set conceallevel=2`
`:set concealcursor=nvi`
So when I write `123456` in vim I expect it to be nothing there. But what actually happens when I move over that area is that I have to move 6 times in the direction I want to move for the cursor to pass that area.

Is there a way to work around this? I want vim to see it as if there is nothing there and that when I move over that area it's like there is nothing there. But I still want to be able to search for it and delete it.

Comment: Sadly I don't think this feature exists

Comment: How would you delete it with `d{motion}` if it didn't register as cursor positions? Despite the conceal feature, Vim still fundamentally is a text editor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in way to do this. You can use `synconcealed()` to determine whether there is a concealed character under the cursor and what it is concealed to and remap all moving keys to respect it: like this:

```
function! ForwardSkipConceal(count)
    let cnt=a:count
    let mvcnt=0
    let c=col('.')
    let l=line('.')
    let lc=col('$')
    let line=getline('.')
    while cnt
        if c>=lc
            let mvcnt+=cnt
            break
        endif
        if stridx(&concealcursor, 'n')==-1
            let isconcealed=0
        else
            let [isconcealed, cchar, group]=synconcealed(l, c)
        endif
        if isconcealed
            let cnt-=strchars(cchar)
            let oldc=c
            let c+=1
            while c<lc && synconcealed(l, c)[2]==group | let c+=1 | endwhile
            let mvcnt+=strchars(line[oldc-1:c-2])
        else
            let cnt-=1
            let mvcnt+=1
            let c+=len(matchstr(line[c-1:], '.'))
        endif
    endwhile
    return ":\<C-u>\e".mvcnt.'l'
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> l ForwardSkipConceal(v:count1)
```

. Note: this does the thing for one single motion (`l`) and in normal mode, just to show the way it may be done.

Comment: The way the function works puts the cursor at the end of the line every time you go past a concealed item. I'm guessing it's because of the `let lc=col('$')` and that you never change it. I tested the function and it works when I put `let lc=col('6')` ,  so I'm accepting it, while I'm thinking I can still make it work :)   
Edit: Still new to writing vim function.

Comment: @plitter When testing on vim help file it did not do this. Nor it should not do this: `lc` is a abbreviation for “last column”: it is used to handle `virtualedit` case when you can move your cursor past line and also the case when concealed item is the last one in the line. In both cases there is exactly no need to change it. I do not know why your change worked, but it is definitely not the right thing to do and it would not fix anything, just mask one problem by creating another.

Comment: @plitter Addition: it was intended to do the first. I forgot to replace `col('$')` with `lc`, now did this.

Comment: Can you say on which file with which syntax highlighting did you test it?

Comment: I agree and it is a horrible fix on my part, from what I can tell it only stops the counter to go past 6 and in my case with the example above it is only supposed to move 6 characters. And hardcoding a constant there will only work in some cases. Hmm, I tested some more and it does what it is supposed to do when I have the filetype set to cpp, but when the filetype is not set the cursor moves to the end.

Comment: @plitter Unable to reproduce the problem with empty filetype (with unnamed buffer that opens once you launch vim with no file arguments). I do not see what can possibly be broken by unsetting filetype. What problem I do observe is that if you remove `n` from 'concealcursor' option (I tested on help files, it is there by default. And it must be there in your case or you’ve not asked this question in first place) then my code wrongly thinks that the character is concealed when it is actually not. The fix is obvious, see update.

Comment: Weird, then the problem is on my part... Do you have your vimfiles on github? Mine are at https://github.com/plitter/vim_config_files and what version of vim do you have?

Comment: @plitter https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim (it is vim version I have, not the vim files) (vim-7.3.659 with some my patches. I did nothing to displaying or input system at the time though). Using HUGE version with all interpreters except racket (mzscheme) (it crashes when I try to do anything with this interface). Default runtime files are from vim-7.3.646 from Gentoo repository. No config to be shared (I have a repo, but I’m not making it public).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16653/discussion-between-plitter-and-zyx)

Answer (score 5):

ZyX's solution from above did not work for me: apparently the ID of a concealed text region can change while traversing it, causing the motion to stop prematurely.

I have been using an alternate version pasted below (also with the missing `BackwardSkipConceal` function). It's not pretty but works well when substituting mathematical characters in LaTeX documents or C++ code.

```
function! ForwardSkipConceal(count)
    let cnt=a:count
    let mvcnt=0
    let c=col('.')
    let l=line('.')
    let lc=col('$')
    let line=getline('.')
    while cnt
        if c>=lc
            let mvcnt+=cnt
            break
        endif
        if stridx(&concealcursor, 'n')==-1
            let isconcealed=0
        else
            let [isconcealed, cchar, group] = synconcealed(l, c)
        endif
        if isconcealed
            let cnt-=strchars(cchar)
            let oldc=c
            let c+=1
            while c < lc
              let [isconcealed2, cchar2, group2] = synconcealed(l, c)
              if !isconcealed2 || cchar2 != cchar
                  break
              endif
              let c+= 1
            endwhile
            let mvcnt+=strchars(line[oldc-1:c-2])
        else
            let cnt-=1
            let mvcnt+=1
            let c+=len(matchstr(line[c-1:], '.'))
        endif
    endwhile
    return ":\<C-u>\e".mvcnt.'l'
endfunction

function! BackwardSkipConceal(count)
    let cnt=a:count
    let mvcnt=0
    let c=col('.')
    let l=line('.')
    let lc=0
    let line=getline('.')
    while cnt
        if c<=1
            let mvcnt+=cnt
            break
        endif
        if stridx(&concealcursor, 'n')==-1 || c == 0
            let isconcealed=0
        else
            let [isconcealed, cchar, group]=synconcealed(l, c-1)
        endif
        if isconcealed
            let cnt-=strchars(cchar)
            let oldc=c
            let c-=1
            while c>1
              let [isconcealed2, cchar2, group2] = synconcealed(l, c-1)
              if !isconcealed2 || cchar2 != cchar
                  break
              endif
              let c-=1
            endwhile
            let c = max([c, 1])
            let mvcnt+=strchars(line[c-1:oldc-2])
        else
            let cnt-=1
            let mvcnt+=1
            let c-=len(matchstr(line[:c-2], '.$'))
        endif
    endwhile
    return ":\<C-u>\e".mvcnt.'h'
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> l ForwardSkipConceal(v:count1)
nnoremap <expr> h BackwardSkipConceal(v:count1)
```

Comment: Almost! For me, concealed id changes every call so I can only rely on first var from synconcealed(). See it working here [Improve movement on concealed text](https://github.com/albfan/ag.vim/commit/bdccf94877401035377aafdcf45cd44b46a50fb5)